# Fibonacci using `for` and `if`

Tags: javascript

Why does the below code return `array = []` for `n = 0`?
I would like it to return `array = [0]`.

And for `n = 1` it returns `array = [0]`?
I would like it to return `array = [0,1]`.

For `n > 1` everything works fine.

```js
let n = prompt("enter number")
let array = []
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (i < 2) {
        array.push(i);
    } else {
        let fib = (array[(i-2)] + array[i-1]);
        array.push(fib);
    }
}
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Change `i < n` to `i <= n` and you'll get what you want.

Comment: Your loop condition is `i < n`. If `n` is `0` and `i` is `0`, then `i` isn't less than `n`.

Comment: thank you for the explaination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition is `i < n`. If `i = 0`, then `i` is not less than `n`. Instead of checking that `i < n`, check that `i <= n`.

**Fixed Code:**

```js
let n = prompt("enter number");
let array = [];
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { // FIXED HERE
    if (i < 2) {
        array.push(i);
    } else {
        let fib = array[i - 2] + array[i - 1];
        array.push(fib);
    }
}
console.log(array);
```